# iced: How to create window in fullscreen?

Tags: user-interface, rust

I can't find any examples, neither [the documentation](https://docs.rs/iced/0.3.0/iced/) nor looking around in [GitHub](https://github.com/hecrj/iced) gives me any idea how to create a window in fullscreen mode.

Have anyone figured it out?

Comment: Hello, this might help? I haven't dug any more yet.
https://github.com/hecrj/iced/blob/master/winit/src/settings.rs, line 159. And  https://github.com/hecrj/iced/blob/master/winit/src/conversion.rs line 195

Answer (score 2):

Untested but from reading the examples and digging around the repo, there is a [`mode`](https://github.com/hecrj/iced/blob/663c3685da4140c9224ae6b189245c991508624b/src/application.rs#L163) method on the `Application` trait. Implementing this method for your application and returning `window::Mode::Fullscreen` might be enough.

```
impl Application for App {
    ...
    fn mode(&self) -> window::Mode {
        window::Mode::Fullscreen
    }
}
```

2023 EDIT: This method was [removed in 2022](https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/commit/277b848ad8df1e8d038e33707548a45d63a601db) and is no longer valid for new versions.

Answer (score 1):

In the Application impl for your app inside the `new` method you can use the [window::change_mode](https://docs.rs/iced/latest/iced/window/fn.change_mode.html#) function to set the window mode to fullscreen.

```
struct App;

impl Application for App {
    ...
    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (App, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (App, window::change_mode(iced::window::Mode::Fullscreen))
    }
    ...
}
```